# How can I automatically set the application version and other such constants for a C# app in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In AssemblyInfo.cs for each project in the solution I have this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(AssemblySettings.ApplicationVersion)]
```

And the constant is defined in AssemblySettings.cs in one of the projects like so:

```
public const string ApplicationVersion =
"2.21.01.01"
;
```

My question is, is there any way to automatically set this constant (and others) in the build pipeline, so I don't have to set it manually before each build?

This particular constant is formatted like so: V.YY.MM.vv where V is the major application version, YY is the last 2 digits of the year, MM is the month, and vv is the ordinal of the release in the month (e.g. 01 for the first release of the month).

The other constants are just string representations of numbers that get incremented by one with each release.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue with getting your formatting as your last part is not available. However you can check [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```yaml
name: 2.$(Year:yy).$(Date:MM).$(Rev:.r)

steps:
  - script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

I placed at the end `$(Rev:.r)` however it is not exactly what you want. You can use variable group and keep variable there which you increment each run, and when you detect that a new month start then reset this variable.

You can use for that puprose `az pipelines variable-group variable update`. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_variable_group_variable_update). For that you also need Azure Cli task.

However, if you decide for that then you need to create variable on your own (not via my first example).

Once you have it - you can use [Assembly Info extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task)